# How to set specific chown and chmod permissions against a SMB/CIFS mount

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs, smb

I currently have a SMB/CIFS network share which I have mounted under /var/inbound to receive files via SFTP. Here is what I have in my /etc/fstab:

```
//somename.file.core.windows.net/inbound /var/inbound cifs vers=3.0,username=somename,password=AccessKeyThatEndsWith==,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

Now I want to have my users jailed at /var/inbound// and they would be uploading their files to /var/inbound//uploads.

Everything would work as expected if /var/inbound/ is just another directory in my Linux filesystem (I tested it). The issue starts when /var/inbound/ is in fact a mount of my SMB/CIFS network share. Users simply cannot connect using an SFTP Client (like FileZilla).

This all has to do with chown and chmod permission settings, and basically I need to be able to perform the following:

```
sudo chown testuser:sftponly /var/inbound/testuser/uploads
sudo chmod ug+rwX /var/inbound/testuser/uploads
```

The above works perfectly with a Linux filesystem but (by design) it would not work with a SMB/CIFS fileshare -- which is why I am experiencing errors. I understand that there could be some mapping that I could do in order to get the desired result, but I have no idea on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be closer to what you want if you add some more options to the end of your fstab entry:

```
,uid=testuser,gid=sftponly
```

Comment: But what if I have additional users? Say testuser1, testuser2, etc?

Comment: That would need multiple users to exist on your server too. Look at `man mount.cifs`.